# Erro no mysql_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysql

Não sei o que acontece neste erro.

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from usuarios");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row["Id"];
    echo $row["Nome"];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para acessar o retorno de `mysql_fetch_object()` use essa sintaxe:

```
$row->nome_da_chave;
```

Se quiser utilizar arrays associativos utilize `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, para acessar os itens basta

```
$row['nome_da_chave'];
```

É altamente recomendável utilizar o [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ou [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) para efetuar conexão com banco de dados, pois as funções `mysql_*` já foram depreciadas e logo serão removidas.

[Motivos para não utilizar as funções mysql_*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/porque-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

A função `mysql_fetch_object` retorna um objeto do tipo `\StdClass`. Para retornar um array, use a função `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você utiliza o mysql_fetch_object o retorno do ponteiro é sempre um objeto do tipo stdClass, por isso, você não pode referencia-lo com os Colchetes pois apenas arrays são referenciados assim, para referencia-lo assim você deve utilizar o mysql_fetch_assoc ou mysql_fetch_array.

```
//utilizando mysql_fetch_assoc
$result = mysql_query("select * from usuarios");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["Id"];
    echo $row["Nome"];
}

//utilizando mysql_fetch_object
$result = mysql_query("select * from usuarios");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->Id;
    echo $row->Nome;
}
```

documentação
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

Answer (score 0):

para objetos utilize `mysql_fetch_object`
para array utilize `mysql_fetch_array`
para array associativos `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Você não fez menção ao motivo do erro, apenas colocou informações soltas. Sua resposta poderia ser um pouco mais explicativa, relacionando o que você disse ao problema enfrentado.